# maven clean install lost resource folder

Tags: maven, build, resources, installation

I was trying to use maven to build my project 
when I create a source folder *src/main/resource* and put a file into that folder.

But when I do "mvn clean install eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse", src/main/resource folder gone, it appears to the *src* folder instead

The problem of this new structure for me is that I have to manually create a *src/main/resource* folder again to make sure that those files in the resource folder could be deployed into classpath when I run it. I wonder if there is a way to let maven do it automatically for me? Thanks

Comment: Don't use mvn eclipse:elcipse anymore. I assume your are using an up-to-date eclispe (like Juno) you don't need to do that anymore. Just import the project into Eclipse. Furthermore the folder is called **src/main/resources** instead of **src/main/resource**. If you do this correct it works out of the box. Of course you need to add this folder to your VCS and commit the contents of it.

Comment: Thanks, I change the folder name and now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the resources directory in pom.xml. Following is the example:

```
<build>
    <directory>target</directory>
    <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <finalName>${artifactId}-${version}</finalName>
    <testOutputDirectory>target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
  </build>
```

reference: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I want to take as a reference to control my package building.